# Clear a GlassPane for Cursor Subsitute

Tags: java, cursor, components, paint, glasspane

is there any way to clear a glasspane without having to repaint the other components?
I am currently trying to make a cursor substitute, as I cant customize real cursor in the way I would like to do. Therefore it is necessary that the substitute is painted very often.

Please do not refer to the API or Oracle Tutorial. I read both of it + about 2 hours internet search. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If the reason you need to do this is that you can't customizethe cursor in the way you want to, why not figure out how to customize the cursor in the way you want to?

Comment: I want the cursor to be of a dynamic size up to almost the whole screen size, which afaik is prevented by the operating system.

Comment: I have no idea what I did, but it works now.

Comment: NVM, it only worked because of a nullpointer exception >.< .